# Issues with invoke-command -scriptblock with double {} and BCDEDIT

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to use powershell to commit a Windows BCD change. That BCDEDIT change line looks like this if run from a regular command line:

```
bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No
```

BCDEDIT requires being run as an admin, so i've got a powershell script that's called from a scheduled task, and the script itself is really simple, as follows:

```
invoke-command -scriptblock {start-process -Verb RunAS bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No}
```

However, when i run that, i get the following:

```
Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named    
parameters. At line:1 char:1

+ invoke-command "bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command],      ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :     AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

I'm assuming i need to wrap the {default} command somehow because it's already in a { } via the -scriptblock section - how would I proceed?

I probably could just use a plain-ol' DOS cmd script, but i want to use PowerShell as I like the logging features/etc and i'm performing other functions with the same script.

Owen

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, i just tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try to put {default} between " ? I.e.: "{default}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the code into these and it worked.

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Start-Process bcdedit -Verb RunAS -ArgumentList "/set {default} recoveryenabled NO"}
```

The bunch of things after `bcdedit`, `/set {default} recoveryenabled No` are actually `bcdedit`'s parameters. You have to start the process of `bcdedit` and pass the rest of the things as its parameter.

Comment: Thanks so much! WORKED!

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Invoke-Expression** cmdlet instead.

```
invoke-command -scriptblock {Invoke-Expression "RunAS bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No"}
```

PS. Make sure you are using correct RunAs arguments.

Comment: Looks like this would have worked as well, thanks as well :)